Column width sizing - CSS Grid VS Html Table
I'm looking for making Admin table like here for example :

source: https://codepen.io/maurice-stitzinger/pen/ZENQqRN
Until now, I was mainly using CSS Grid (each row being a div with display grid) but I heard that's a bad practice and that using <table> is really important, at least for semantics and SEO.
Though, I have a lot trouble finding how to manage column width. The exemple above seems to have achieved this, but I don't even understand how.
In my version I have 6 columns : ID | Thumb | Nom | Version | Logo | Action and I want all of them (except Thumb and logo maybe) to take a certain part of the width, as I would with a Css Grid.
Ideally I want the Thumb column having an auto width depending on image's width (like it would work with grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 2fr 2fr 1fr 1fr
I absolutely want to avoid horizontal scroll, so I will make some columns disappear with CSS properties on medium and small screens.
The question now is, considering how I want to manage this table, is using <table> a real advantage since it's causing a lot of problem ? And if yes, how I could achieve this kind of columns sizing.
And why would using CSS grid like I'm doing would be such a bad practice since it's offering me all I need.

I've never heard that a CSS grid is bad practice.  Where did you get that?  As to your question, the <th> and <td> tags both have a width attribute that can be specified as a percentage of the table.

@TimRoberts Oh you're right for the width attribute, I thought we had to avoid using it, and there was attribute to manage table like we would do with grid-template-columns
I heard that it's a bad practice when asking people around me, the points put forward were mainly semantic (such as using a  instead of a  to make a button) and the fact that I would have to write a lot of aria-XXX properties in the CSS.

There's a lot of religious nonsense in web coding.  I'd use a table with widths.

But can we manage columns with image only to make them able to resize depending on their contents ? This wouldn't be a problem to have such a column while setting other columns' width ?

Table layouts, are by all accounts, not sane, and one of the principal drivers behind the creation of CSS Grid was to provide a 2D layout with greater control. But note that HTML tables and CSS Grid are not mutually incompatible, you can apply a CSS Grid to an HTML table and get the best of both.

@Alohci Wait, is this possible ? How ? By putting display grid on all tr ? I have to try that

You can use display: contents on table rows and row groups to flatten the table structure into a sequence of CSS boxes that can be placed as desired into a CSS grid, or grid-template-rows: subgrid to make a table row one row of a a grid.

Correction: It's getting late. I meant grid-template-columns, not grid-template-rows,


What do you think about using fixed layout?

Tables might be better in some ways because they are recognizable as structured data representations.
     table-layout: fixed;
     width: 100%;
 }

 th, td {
     padding: 10px;
 }

 th:nth-child(1) { width: 10%; }
 th:nth-child(2) { width: 10%; }
 th:nth-child(3) { width: 30%; }
 th:nth-child(4) { width: 20%; }
 th:nth-child(5) { width: 20%; }
 th:nth-child(6) { width: 10%; }```





I guess this can work, but would this layout fix still work if we included a column containing only images of the same size and wanted its width to be automatic?

@Akihiro if you want to achieve similar functionality with images in columns like in the photo you provided, that could be done in many ways, I think that fixed layout would work.
